# VSTO Addin same buttons multiple tab

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins

Working on the VSTO Add-in for Outlook. Is there anyway to avoid duplicating the whole ribbon XML code if I just want the same buttons to appear under two different tab/view (TabCalendar and TabMail)
My ribbon code is the following:

```
<ribbon>
  <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabMail">
      <button id="ID1" label="XxX" onAction="OnTextButton" image="myImg1" size="large" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
      <button id="ID2" label="XxX" onAction="OnTextButton" image="myImg2" size="large" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
      ...
    </tab>
    <tab idMso="TabCalendar">
      <button id="SameThanID1" label="XxX" onAction="OnTextButton" image="myImg1" size="large" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
      <button id="SameThanID2" label="XxX" onAction="OnTextButton" image="myImg2" size="large" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
     ...
    </tab>
  </tabs>
</ribon>
```

What I would love to to is:

```
<ribbon>
  <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabMail" OR "TabCalendar">
      <button id="ID1" label="XxX" onAction="OnTextButton" image="myImg1" size="large" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
      <button id="ID2" label="XxX" onAction="OnTextButton" image="myImg2" size="large" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
      ...
    </tab>
  </tabs>
</ribon>
```

It is really annoying as the button needs to be unique and I therefore have to duplicate the same logic. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580814/how-to-add-a-group-to-multiple-built-in-ribbon-tabs-vsto) which is not really encouraging. Is there any option?

Comment: No, you have to repeat it in the XML, as you show in your first code snippet.

Comment: Ok too bad but thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't allow to combine built-in tabs markup and place the ribbon XML into a single place. You need to specify (repeat) the markup for each built-in tab separately. Read more about the ribbon UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)